# How do I account for a variable number of extra arguments in a bash script?

Tags: pipe, stat

It is set up so that `$1` is the flag for what the program is going to do, `$2` can be a username or anything else. This works great except for one thing: I have to be able to add a comment to a user, and that screws things up, since I don't know how many words they are going to type. How do I solve this?

Comment: I suggest you split this question into two parts so that there's one topic in each. Once you've done that please provide examples of what you have and what you want to do, clearly explaining what in your current code isn't right and what you want instead. Remember we don't need to see your entire program, but instead create a small example script that illustrates the issue at hand.

Comment: We have a strict one question per question policy. I will remove 2nd question, it will still be in the history. Make a new question.

Answer (score 2):

Some suggestions:

- Make the user put the comment in quotes, so that it is one argument:

  ```
  command arg1 "a long comment with many spaces" arg3
  ```
- Have the comment be at the end:

  If user calls `command arg1 arg2 a long comment with many spaces`
  Then you can use `shift` to remove earlier arguments, then `$*` to capture all remaining:

  ```
  arg1="$1" #use a better name
  arg2="$2"
  shift
  shift
  comment="$*"
  ```

Comment: `shift 2` maybe instead.